# Is there a way to include an empty/null value for an xsd:dateTime?

Tags: xml, xsd

Using an xsd:dateTime data type, is there a way to specify an optional/null time component?

```
e.g. 2012-02-29T00:00:00-06:00 - this would mean midnight
     2012-02-29T-06:00         - invalid as all parts are required
```

We could use two fields for the date and time but we then have the issue of how best to carry the UTC offset for each field since these fields are logically related.  It is impossible to convert EffectiveDate (i.e. adjusting a day for rollover) without knowing about the EffectiveTime since these are logically together.

```
    <EffectiveDate>2012-02-29-06:00</EffectiveDate>  
    <EffectiveTime>07:01-06:00</EffectiveTime>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to implement it with an optional/null component. However, I am not seeing why it wouldn't work with two fields, based on what you've described; As long as by convention you consider them coherent and correct, AND always timezoned (both fields should carry the timezone offset, dealing with local is always a pain in long term), then two fields vs. one is just a "waste" of one time zone information.

I know it is a dry reading, but I would revisit the definitions of date and time found [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/), particularly focusing on "**time** represents an instant of time that recurs every day" and "Timezoned **date** values track the starting moment of their day, as determined by their timezone" to see if they would match the requirements you seem to have.